# script going to each IP on host file, then execute script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have been doing a lot of research but cant find a way to get a powershell script to look at a host file and then go to each host name and pull the logs and save them at one place, I have a script going that will pull the logs but on local host only.  What can I do to get the script to go to each machine and execute my script?

Thats the beef of it I have other steps for putting it into a file just want to know how I can use the command you mentioned to jump to each machine and collect those files.

```
$computers = get-content C:\MyScripts\MachineNames.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-7)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy"), $env:Computername
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date 

| Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
| foreach-Object 
$row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
$row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
$row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
$row # this will put the current row to the pipeline 
} | Export-Csv 'c:\output.csv
```

Now I am getting:  At line:9 char:1
+ | Where -FilterScript {$*.EventID -eq 4624 -and $*.ReplacementStrings[4].Length  ...
+ ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:15 char:3
+ } | Export-Csv 'c:\output.csv
+   ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:15 char:16
+ } | Export-Csv 'c:\output.csv
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Answer (score 0):

use psexec.exe or extend your code to read remote machine

do you want to share your script so some one can look at it and extend the capability?

Comment: Frédéric Bonneau provided a good answer on yours. but the $env:computername is local host. also your script have not gone to every machine, just repeat on the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct script to use

```
$computers = get-content C:\MyScripts\MachineNames.txt

$Result = foreach ($computer in $computers)  {

$Date = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-1)
$Date.tostring("MM-dd-yyyy"), $env:Computername
Get-EventLog "Security" -After $Date | Where-object -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} |
foreach-Object {
$row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
$row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
$row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
$row # this will put the current row to the pipeline 

                 } 
}
$Result | Export-Csv C:\MyScripts\output.csv
```